# Enable the 1-Password extension on the StackExchange iOS app login page

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

(I have a feeling this one’s been asked too, but again, not finding it.)

Please consider enabling the 1-Password extension on the StackExchange iOS app login page.

Answer (score 1):

That feature request is also on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220983/add-1password-support-to-the-ios-app) and has [status-deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred).

I expect that means not within 6 to 8 weeks...

Comment: Well the post is more than a year old I think, so hopefully sooner than that...

Comment: You know the [meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514), right?